# Why are the *_leastN_t and *_fastN_t types required, not optional?

Tags: c++, c99, stdint, cstdint

We all know that the exact-width integer typedefs defined in C99's `stdint.h` are optional, being defined only if the architecture has primitive types of those widths, signs, etc.

However, I just now realised that `[u]int_(fast|least)N_t` are *not* optional, but **required**. See ISO/IEC 9899:9999, section 7.18.1:

> [7.18.1.2] **3** The following types are required:
>
> ```
> int_least8_t
> int_least16_t
> int_least32_t
> int_least64_t
> uint_least8_t
> uint_least16_t
> uint_least32_t
> uint_least64_t
> ```

> [7.18.1.3] **3** The following types are required:
>
> ```
> int_fast8_t
> int_fast16_t
> int_fast32_t
> int_fast64_t
> uint_fast8_t
> uint_fast16_t
> uint_fast32_t
> uint_fast64_t
> ```

So, as read, all architectures that can offer a Standard-compliant C or C++ compiler - including freestanding ones, seeing as `stdint.h` is required in those - must be capable of providing primitive types of at least 64 bits!

Given the Standard's leeway on so many other implementation details, this seems bizarre to me. That's especially because apparently we have been enforcing it since 1999, some years before 64-bit computing became mainstream even on the desktop. That's to say nothing of the lag behind that among, in many cases still current, embedded architectures.

What was the rationale for requiring all implementations to have primitive types of at least 64 bits? And, since this surely has severe implications for implementors in practice, how have they reacted to/dealt with this?

(...or what have I missed in my reading, is always an answer too)

Comment: All of the `least` types can be satisfied by some fundamental type, since the ranges of representable values of fundamental types require at least `long long int` to have at least 64 bits. Your question could therefore be simplified to why `long long int` is a thing in C.

Comment: The question should be the other way around: why are the fixed-size type optional? And the answer is that they might not exist, so they can't be required. The fast and least variants can be implemented on all conforming compilers.

Comment: Also, requiring 64-bit integers is not a "severe" issue for implementors. Back in the days when most systems had 16-bit processors, `long` had to be at least 32 bits, and implementors provide software implementation of 32-bit math to support it.

Comment: The "64" in "64-bit computing" refers to pointer size, not available integer arithmetic sizes.  64-bit integers have been common longer.

Comment: Interesting points, thanks! @PeteBecker I didn't ask that opposite question because I know the answer to it, which is obvious.

Answer (score 1):

You are correct that all C and C++ implementations must supply a type of at least 64 bits - but it isn't just `uint_least64_t` and `int_least64_t` that force that.  The minimum range for `unsigned long long int` and `long long int` require 64 bits too.

Why did the standards committee think it was worth requiring a 64-bit type?  Hard to tell, but probably because *most* architectures have one available, and those that don't can implement it via library functions (which won't be linked if they aren't used).

Comment: This is a good point that I didn't think of yet. I guess the real question, then, is why the `long long int`s have the minimal requirements they do. Perhaps that'll provide better fuel for my searches. I also think I was considering the nature of primitive types on too basic a level, as requiring corresponding hardware registers, when of course a compiler can actually implement them however it wants.

Comment: `long` already requires at least 32 bits, so `long long` is only worthwhile if it is longer.  In practise, that means 64 bits.  `long` hasn't been large enough for disk sizes and large files for about 20 or 30 years.